# Glucan rest necessary

Tags: mash, techniques

I am brewing all-grain and have in the past always held a glucan rast when mashing. I am trying to speed up my brewing process and that rest of course slows me down quite a bit because of the heating up afterwards. Has anyone had bad experiences without glucan rests? Do you think a glucan rest is necessary and if so with all malts or just with some (e.g. wheat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A beta glucan rest help convert starches made up of long strands of glucose molecules.  These are typically found in oats, wheat and rye.  If you have a low percentage of those malts you can skip the stage.

### Try it out

See if you can detect a change in the beer.

Comment: Well, I guess I do learn something new everyday!  It's great having guys like you on this site.  Thanks.